# iPhone 6 and 6 plus scaled up screen icons

Tags: ios, ios8, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I am using scaled up views for iPhone 6 and 6 plus for my app i.e. I haven't added splash screen for iPhone 6 and 6 plus.

I would like to know will the iPhone 6 and 6 plus will use high definition images (@3x) or as it is only scaled up app so will use retina images (@2x).

Kindly let me know if anyone has came across this.

Comment: I would imagine the iPhone 6 will use 2x images and the iPhone 6+ 3x as only the + has x3 resolution. This is assuming you use the resolution based naming conventions for your files.

Comment: It will only take images for which you provide to iPhone5 size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your reply.

Today I created one POC using 1x, 2x and 3x image and tested it on simulator. Look like application is using high definition image for iPhone 6 plus. I have attached images for reference.

I don't have device to test this POC. Hope this will behave same on device.

[image: iPhone 5s]

[image: iPhone 6![][2]]

Answer (score 1):

It will not use @3x images until you add launch screens.